# Why setImeOptions doesn't work? Same for setTextSize

Tags: android, textview, ime

My code:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
final EditText newPositionName = new EditText(this);

newPositionName.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH);
newPositionName.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

I can't understand why setImeOptions doesn't work! setBackgroundColor works fine.
Same for setTextSize. I've:

```
private Vector<TextView> ranking = new Vector<TextView>();
...
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    ranking.add(new TextView(this));
    ranking.lastElement().setTextSize(30);
}
```

But text size doesn't change.

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13561808/setimeoptions-why-the-done-button-does-not-show-on-the-soft-keyboard

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out here: [setImeOptions: why the "Done" button does not show on the soft keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13561808/setimeoptions-why-the-done-button-does-not-show-on-the-soft-keyboard)
calling `setSingleLine()` on the TextEdit will enable the functionality.